# Compile python files + all dependecies + intepreter into one java\.net (dll or exe) file?

Tags: java, python, .net, dependencies

I have a couple of python files with some dependencies on third-party libraries, like pyaudio. So is there a way to compile everything including python intepreter itself into one .jar\dll file to use them in java\android or xamarin\ .net core, without actual installing python + doing pip install  every time?
Also as an option - compile into c\c++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know about compiling into C, but for compiling executables in general you can use pyinstaller, cx_freeze, or a few other less common modules to create an executable folder which contains all the `.dll` files to run the program. I only have experience with cx_freeze so I'll discuss that here. If your goal is to have the end-user have only 1 "file" show up when they download it you need to use an installer program. To semi-quote cx_freeze documentation at: https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html

> cx_Freeze does not support building a single file exe, where all of the libraries for your application are embedded in one executable file. [There are modules that do this, but it's my understanding they use "hacks" that *can* get them flagged by antivirus software.]
>
> You can use **IExpress** to compress the build directory from cx_Freeze into a self-extracting archive: an exe which unpacks your application into a temporary directory and runs it. IExpress is a utility that’s included with Windows, intended for making installers, but it works equally well if you tell it to run the cx_Freeze-built exe after extraction.
>
> Alternatively, you can create a self extracting archive using 7zip. This is a bit more complex than using IExpress, but might provide more flexibility, and allows you to build your application using only open source tools.

Alternatively you can compile with `python setup.py bdist_msi` to create a single `.msi` file which will let the user choose where they want to install the program. At the end of the day the user will still have a directory with all the `.dll` files and whatnot, but they get to choose where they tuck that stuff away on their hard drive! I think this is the method most applications I've installed use. This is assuming you develop on Windows as well, if not you should include your OS on your post.

Comment: Thank you for comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can use PyInstaller to create an executable. 
Use this command:

`pyinstaller --onefile <your_script>.py`

https://medium.com/dreamcatcher-its-blog/making-an-stand-alone-executable-from-a-python-script-using-pyinstaller-d1df9170e263